What is the significance of the 'one word' in Gabriela Mistral's poem Una palabra
In Gabriela Mistral's poem Una palabra (literally "one word"), the speaker says (in the first stanza, from the translation in Mapping a different star: five poems by Gabriela Mistral),

I have one word in my throat
and I can’t get it out, can’t get free of it
however hard its throb of blood pushes.
If I did spit it out, it would scorch the grass,
drain the lamb of blood, make birds fall from the sky.

In the third stanza, she also says,

My father Job may have uttered it, blazing,
but I don’t want my pathetic mouth to give it voice—
it might roll off and be discovered by the women
who go to the river, get tangled in their hair,
and leave the pitiful thickets burnt and ravaged.

Job had seven sons and “three daughters named Jemimah (which means "dove"), Keziah ("cinnamon"), and Keren-happuch ("horn of eye-makeup"). His daughters were said to be the most beautiful women in the land.” However, since the speaker is not certain whether Job uttered the word, it is not clear whether (re)reading the Book of Job is even helpful.
What is the significance of this word that seems to be too dangerous to speak?

It seems to me that the "word" is a bad swear word.
The speaker in the poem says

If I did spit it out, it would scorch the grass,
drain the lamb of blood, make birds fall from the sky.

These are stereotypical effects of swear words.

I don’t want to give any sign of what I’m living though
as it comes and goes with my blood,
rises and sinks with my mad breath.

If she says the swear word, she lets everyone who hears it know that something is really wrong. And she doesn’t want anybody to know.

nor to recall that fateful night:
the residence in a foreign country,
the ambush, the lightning at the door,
my flesh continuing to function without a soul!

So something really bad happened to her, which explains why she wants to say that swear word.
I really don't know anything about Spanish swear words, so I don't know whether there's one obvious one that Mistral has in mind or not. I suspect not.

Based on the poem's content, I would expect something much more serious than a swear word; something at least at the level of profanity in the original sense of that word (treating sacred things with contempt). Or extreme despair, which can be a sin in Christianity.
